# MySQL - use data in column if available else use another column

Tags: mysql

I have an application which is built in PHP and uses PDO for talking to a MySQL database.

The database has a table of training courses. The structure of the table is such that there are "start date" and "end date" `DATE` fields for courses:

```
courses.start_date
courses.end_date
```

All courses have a start date, but the end date is optional. This is because the course may be run for an afternoon, or over a period of days (e.g. 6 - 8 March).

I have 2 pages in my application which list "upcoming courses" (occurring after today's date) and "past courses" (have occurred before today's date).

The only query condition I could reliably use was based on `courses.start_date` because that field is always populated. So the part where my query filtering was being done looks like this:

```
if ($when == 'future') {
    $sql .= " AND courses.start_date >= CURDATE()";
}
    
if ($when == 'past') {
     $sql .= " AND courses.start_date < CURDATE()";
}
```

If I change the conditions to use `courses.end_date` (instead of `start_date`) it won't return any data for courses which do not have an end date. For example, this *won't* work:

```
courses.start_date = '2017-03-06'
courses.end_date = NULL
```

But this *will* work, because it has an end date:

```
courses.start_date = '2017-03-06'
courses.end_date = '2017-03-08'
```

I would like to know if it's possible using an SQL query to use `end_date` if there is one, else use `start_date`. As the application is already in PHP I considered looping through my data and dynamically adding conditions; but this seems inefficient if there is a pure SQL way to do this.

### Edit

I've already accepted an answer which works perfectly. However someone has commented and asked for sample data and expected results. Consider using the application today (2017-03-07). If we have:

```
courses.start_date = '2017-03-06'
courses.end_date = '2017-03-08'
```

that course hasn't finished yet; it's still going on until tomorrow.

In my original code it was only querying on `courses.start_date` so the application will move this to the "past courses" page, because `2017-03-06` is "before today" (`< CURDATE()`). I could change the query so it used `courses.end_date` and that would have met my needs.

**However** not all of the courses have an end date, so I could not simply change the query to use that and get the results back in a reliable manner. For example when we had

```
courses.start_date = '2017-03-06'
courses.end_date = NULL
```

the query will not work because there is no `courses.end_date` so it doesn't even find this record.

The answer given allows MySQL to *"use the end date if it's available, else use the start date"*. It saves having to loop through things as it can be done during the initial query.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe loop through all records with the start date and use a `case` to mark the closed ones. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've already accepted an answer but I've edited the post to show what the intention was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COALESCE should do exactly what you need.

You simply pass it a series of values/fields, and it returns the first one which is not null.

So your query would contain :

```
 AND COALESCE(courses.end_date,courses.start_date) < CURDATE()
```